# How to copy animation from one project to another in Camtasia?

Tags: video-editor, editing

I have created some animation in Camtasia studio. When I copy paste them into another camtasia project everything gets messed up, animation effect, start n end position, size etc. I tried to match the resolution size still the same issue.

Is there any proper way of doing this? like creating a template or theme or library media and use in another project.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. Right click on track > add asset to library > open another project > drag that asset to particular track.